# how can I change the location of Log files for SQL Server Reporting Services in sql2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssrs

I tried to change the location of Log files for SQL Server by using these steps but it's not working because I can not find the RTrace in two web config files.

There are three files you need to modify to change the location of the Reporting Services Logfiles. These files are:

- `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Reporting Services\ReportManager\web.config`
- `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Reporting Services\ReportServer\web.config`
- `c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Reporting Services\ReportServer\Bin\ReportingServicesService.exe.config`

Add the following tag under RSTrace in all the above files:

`<add name="Directory" value="c:\directorypath" />`

Your help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can modify the location. This file is located at **\Microsoft SQL Server\\Reporting Services\LogFile**

Tracing levels are specified through DefaultTraceSwitch and RSTrace settings. All trace level settings are stored in the ReportingServicesrService.exe.config file.

The configuration file is found in the folder path **\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS10.\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin**
The File name attribute only affects the file prefix

More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156500(v=SQL.100).aspx